# How to fix graalvm eureka client transport exception while registering with EurekaServer at AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, graalvm

I am doing setup at AWS for Eureka Discovery for my services running at EC2 instances inside graalVM .
But facing issue at client below

```
> DiscoveryClient | fetchRegistry | Disable delta property : false
> DiscoveryClient | fetchRegistry | Single vip registry refresh property
> : nul
> 
> DiscoveryClient | fetchRegistry | Force full registry fetch : false
> DiscoveryClient | fetchRegistry | Application is null : false
> DiscoveryClient | fetchRegistry | Registered Applications size is zero
> : true DiscoveryClient | fetchRegistry | Application version is -1:
> true DiscoveryClient | getAndStoreFullRegistry | Getting all instance
> registry info from the eureka server DiscoveryClient |
> getAndStoreFullRegistry | The response status is 200 DiscoveryClient |
> initScheduledTasks | Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is:
> 30 DiscoveryClient | <init> | Discovery Client initialized at
> timestamp 1694962592645 with initial instances count: 0
> DiscoveryClient$3 | notify | Saw local status change event
> StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1694962592921, current=UP,
> previous=STARTING] DiscoveryClient | register |
> DiscoveryClient_<MY_CLIENT_NAME>/<MYHOSTNAME>: registering service...
> RetryableEurekaHttpClient | execute | Request execution failure with
> status code 400; retrying on another server if available
> DiscoveryClient | register |
> DiscoveryClient_<MY_CLIENT_NAME>/<MYHOSTNAME> - registration failed
> Cannot execute request on any known server
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:820)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
>         at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:820)
```

Below are the messages at EurekaServer

```
c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : DS: Registry: lease doesn't exist, registering resource: <MY_CLIENT_NAME> - <MYHOSTNAME>
c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found (Renew): <MY_CLIENT_NAME> - <MYHOSTNAME>
c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

Below are the details for my Eureka Server and Client

EurekaServer: This is not using graalvm and running on EC2 instance. When call the status APi from same machine at which client is running, able to get the status using below command
**curl http://:8761/eureka/apps**
Have made @EnableEurekaServer to My main class and below is my application.properties content

```
    spring.application.name=my-discovery-server
    server.port=8761
    
    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Below are the snippets from pom.xml

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Below are my Client Configurations:
Have placed below dependency inside pom.xml. Needed to exclude the commons-logging as was creating issue for graalvm

org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client
4.0.3


commons-logging
commons-logging

Apart from this , client pom have below other entries which are for other purposes for the application

```
<parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.8</version>
                <relativePath />
        </parent>
     <properties>
                <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                </dependency>
<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
                </dependency>
<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                </dependency>
 <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                        <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Added following to the Configuration class

```
@Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils) {
      EurekaInstanceConfigBean bean = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
      AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
      bean.setDataCenterInfo(info);
      return bean;
    }
```

Below are the settings inside client application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,prometheus
spring.cloud.refresh.enabled=false
eureka.client.enabled=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://<EurekaServerHost>:8761/eureka/
```

Comment: `my-discovery-server` - is this an IP or a DNS name? can you try all of this locally to understand if this is an infra issue or a code issue?